# characteristics of the same Ito processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Hey i have a fairly simple task and please just comment if it is done correctly. I have to show that if two processes

$dX(t)=a_X(t)dt+b_X(t)dW_t$

$dY(t)=a_Y(t)dt+b_Y(t)dW_t$

are equal then $a_X=a_Y$ and $b_X=b_Y$.

I calculate:

$d((X(t)-Y(t))^2=...=2(a_X(t)-a_Y(t))(X_t-Y_t)dt+(b_X-b_Y)^2dt+2(b_X-b_Y)(X_t-Y_t)dW_t$

$\sqrt{(X(t)-Y(t))^2}=X(t)-Y(t)$ so we since on the left we have $0$, then:

$2(a_X(t)-a_Y(t))=0$, so $a_X(t)=a_Y(t)$

$(b_X-b_Y)^2=0$ so $b_X=b_Y$

$a_X,a_Y: P(\{w:\int_0^T|a(s,w)|ds<\infty\})=1$
and $b_X,b_Y\in M_{[0,T]}^2=\left\{f:[0,T]\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:\text{f is adapted}, E\left(\int_0^Tf^2(t)dt\right)<\infty\right\}$

Is my proof correct or do you have any doubts?

Comment: Am I right or there are mistakes in my solution?

Comment: are the coefficient deterministic functions?

Comment: No (edited post)

Comment: And? :D do you see any errors there?